# download .msg attachment to binary array

Tags: c#, vsto

I've VSTO add-in which will store the images into the server. I can convert any type of attachments to the binary array with below lines but unable to get the byte array of the .msg type attachment(Microsoft Mail Attachment). How to convert the .msg file to byte array, is there any api from Microsoft side?

private const string PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x37010102";

attach.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at **MSGReader** from Github user @**Sicos1977**.

> https://github.com/Sicos1977/MSGReader

. It has the code to parse the .msg files. Once it is parsed, you can convert it into any format you want.